# Как закрыть tkinter окно через время

Tags: python, tkinter

Открывается окно, в что-то написано.
Через 5 секунд оно должно завершится,как мне это сделать?
Ещё надо учитывать что это как доп. окно, то-есть есть ещё одно окно, которое должно продолжить работу.
Вот код с окном которое должно завершится:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

window = Tk()  
window.title("123")  
window.overrideredirect(1)

lblc = Label(window, text="Внимание:недостаточно кликов для X2",font=("Arial Bold", 15), background="SystemWindow")  
lblc.grid(column=0, row=0)
window.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно запустить window.destroy() с отложенным исполнением при помощи window.after()

```
window.after(5000, window.destroy)
window.mainloop()
```